# Configurabale parameters for MDB at the time of maven build

Tags: java, maven, ejb

I am creating a mdb using ejb-jar.xml as bellow.

```
<enterprise-beans>
   <message-driven>
    <ejb-name>REFEngineMDB</ejb-name>
    <ejb-class>com.engine.REFEngineMDB</ejb-class>
     <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type> 
     <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
     <activation-config>

      <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>user</activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>userName</activation-config-property-value>
      </activation-config-property>
       <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>password</activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>password</activation-config-property-value>
      </activation-config-property>
     </activation-config>
  </message-driven>
  </enterprise-beans>
```

This is working fine.But i need to make the username and password configurable at the build time.I am using maven.Please suggest how to replace the username and password at the time of maven install.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [filtering feature](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html), aren't you?

Comment: Nop.I want to parametrized the user name and password at the build time.

Comment: And when - you think - does filtering apply?

Comment: Ok, I explain: If you simply enable filtering as described in the link, your build (for example: "mvn install") will apply it. Of course, you must provide the values for the parameters (with "-D...").

Comment: can i apply filtering to any xml or only to pom.xml